How to read a struct from a binary file using windows header file methods like fgetc?
Say I want to serialize some struct
struct SomeStruct
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};


and I go about it using the Windows header file like so
#include "SomeHeader.h" //This is where the header file is
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

FILE* f = fopen("SomeFile.pak", "wb");

SomeStruct data;
data.a = 3;
data.b = 2;
data.c = 5; 

fwrite(&data, sizeof(SomeStruct), 1, f);

fclose(f);

and then I try and open the stuct in a seperate method like
FILE* f = fopen("SomeFile.pak", "rb");
BYTE* databuffer = NULL;
databuffer = new BYTE[sizeof(SomeStruct)];
fread(databuffer, sizeof(SomeStruct), 1, f);

SomeStruct data;
data.a = databuffer[0];
data.b = databuffer[4];
data.c = databuffer[8];

std::cout << data.a << std::endl;
std::cout << data.b << std::endl;
std::cout << data.c << std::endl;

The console reads properly with
3
2
5

It turns out what I was originally doing wrong was not using the correct indices (if assuming all int in the struct, it should be + 4 for every index because of the size of int)
But this new problem I'm running into is if any of the ints are large enough theyll simply not print properly using this method. say I set data.a to 20008, the console will read it as 40 and I have to assume this is from my lack of knowledge of binary and binary files
I've tried with the above example (setting data.a to 20008) and adding index 0 - 3 together, multiplying, etc. but had no luck, not that I was expecting any

The value problem is from databuffer[0]only being one byte. So if the value is too large, it will just not fit. You could either fread directly into data, similar to when writing. Or use memcpy to copy all buffer bytes into the struct.

If you are a beginnner, just stay away from binary data and lookup "binary serialization". If you do it naively you will find it might work on your machine, but then if you compile your code on another machine or other compiler (or even different settings) you might find your data might not load correctly. In general use a library for binary (protobuf/flatbuffer) or something like nlohman-json to persist data in text format.

Read this before you continue : https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/cpptutorial/ (even if you're not going to use it). Since from your question it is already clear you're making assumptions on the memory layout of your struct (but imagine what happens if you move from a 32 to a 64 bit machine)

You asked the same question previously and the same answer applies fread(&data, sizeof(SomeStruct), 1, f); This solves your problem (which is actually about how you transfer the data from your buffer to your actual struct, not about how you do the binary read).

The problem is that your databuffer is a byte array and databuffer[index] is a single byte.
The decimal value 20008 (hex 0x4E28) requires at least 2 bytes (in your case, int is 4 bytes).  Your integers are being written to the file in little-endian format, so 20008 will be stored as the byte sequence 28 4E 00 00. Since you are only looking at the 1st byte of each integer, you will read in the byte value 0x28 (decimal 40).
So, to solve this, you need to read more than 1 byte per integer from your databuffer, eg:
FILE* f = fopen("SomeFile.pak", "rb");
BYTE* databuffer = new BYTE[sizeof(SomeStruct)];
fread(databuffer, sizeof(SomeStruct), 1, f);

SomeStruct data;
memcpy(&data.a, &databuffer[0],             sizeof(int));
memcpy(&data.b, &databuffer[sizeof(int)],   sizeof(int));
memcpy(&data.c, &databuffer[sizeof(int)*2], sizeof(int));

// alternatively:
// data.a = * (int*) &databuffer[0];
// data.b = * (int*) &databuffer[sizeof(int)];
// data.c = * (int*) &databuffer[sizeof(int)*2];

// alternatively:
// int *ptr = (int*) databuffer;
// data.a = *ptr++;
// data.b = *ptr++;
// data.c = *ptr++;

std::cout << data.a << std::endl;
std::cout << data.b << std::endl;
std::cout << data.c << std::endl;

delete[] databuffer;

Or, you can just copy the entire struct in one go:
FILE* f = fopen("SomeFile.pak", "rb");
BYTE* databuffer = new BYTE[sizeof(SomeStruct)];
fread(databuffer, sizeof(SomeStruct), 1, f);

SomeStruct data;
memcpy(&data, databuffer, sizeof(SomeStruct));

// alternatively:
// data = * (SomeStruct*) databuffer;

std::cout << data.a << std::endl;
std::cout << data.b << std::endl;
std::cout << data.c << std::endl;

delete[] databuffer;

However, it would be easier to just get rid of the databuffer altogether and simply read from the file directly into your data struct (same as you do when writing it to the file), eg:
FILE* f = fopen("SomeFile.pak", "rb");

SomeStruct data;
fread(&data, sizeof(SomeStruct), 1, f);

std::cout << data.a << std::endl;
std::cout << data.b << std::endl;
std::cout << data.c << std::endl;

